# Buy now redirection

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I Have a form with two button

1. Add to Cart -> Product Added to the cart and it reload the same page
2. Buy Now --> Product Added to the cart and it should redirect to shopping cart page.

This is the code:

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product'));?>" method="post" id="seller_addtocart_form1" class="ma">
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId(); ?>" name="mpassignproduct_id" class="mpassignproduct_id"/>
    <button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>"
            class="button btn-cart customaddtocart"
            title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>"
            onclick="<?php echo $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>">
        <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag')?></span></span>
    </button>
    <div>
        <button class="button buy-now" onclick="location.href ='{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty=1'">
            <span><span>Buy Now</span></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Both are redirect to same page it self. What mistake I have done?

Answer (score 0):

Keep buy now button out side the form because button has own location href and addtocart link.

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product'));?>" method="post" id="seller_addtocart_form1" class="ma">
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId(); ?>" name="mpassignproduct_id" class="mpassignproduct_id"/>
    <button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>"
            class="button btn-cart customaddtocart"
            title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>"
            onclick="<?php echo $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>">
        <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag')?></span></span>
    </button>
</form>
<div>
   <button class="button buy-now" onclick="location.href='location.href='{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty=1'"> <span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where i have to add after form

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: No it's not working not even to click also

Comment: what error is showing ? and inspect that buy now div and paste that code here.